# google map infowindow cutting off text

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

I have a fixed size infowindow in a google map application.  Problem is that text gets cut off on right side. I tried various techniques, wrapping text in span container, with smaller width. Also played with text-overflow and overflow, but to no avail. Anyone have a good hack for this?

[image]

Comment: It would help a lot to see what you actually have done, so people have a chance to reproduce the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had inadvertently copied in a "white-space: nowrap" directive in css which was causing problem...

```
 /* fix for unwanted scroll bar in InfoWindow */        

 .scrollFix{  
  overflow: hidden;                                     
  /* white-space: nowrap; <--- OUT! */               
  padding-top:3px;                                      
  height:300px !important;                              
  width:350px !important;                               
 }
```